# XSLT 1.0 keys compare multiple keys

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

I have an input xml that looks like

```
<data>
<row>
    <Field1>ABC</Field1>
    <Field2>123</Field2>
    <tag3>BLAH</tag3>
    <tag4>BLAH1</tag4>
</row>
<row>
    <Field1>ABC</Field1>
    <Field2>789</Field2>
    <tag3>BLAH</tag3>
    <tag4>BLAH1</tag4>
</row>
<row>
    <Field1>DEF</Field1>
    <Field2>456</Field2>
    <tag3>BLAH3</tag3>
    <tag4>BLAH4</tag4>
</row>
<row>
    <Field1>456</Field1>
    <Field2>XYZ</Field2>
    <tag3>BLAH5</tag3>
    <tag4>BLAH6</tag4>
</row>
```

Now I have two keys defined like so

```
<xsl:key name="Field1Key" match="data/row/Field1/text()" use="."/>
<xsl:key name="Field2Key" match="data/row/Field2/text()" use="."/>
```

What I'm doing with the keys is to loop over unique values of Field1 and Field2 is

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/row/Field1/text()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Field1Key',.)[1])]">
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>      
    </test>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="data/row/Field2/text()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Field2Key',.)[1])]">
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>      
    </test>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Which gives me an output that looks something like

```
<test>ABC</test>
<test>DEF</test>
<test>456</test>
<test>123</test>
<test>789</test>
<test>456</test>
<test>XYZ</test>
```

so my problem is,

How do I avoid the 456 value from appearing twice? could you please point me to the most effecient way to achieve this as I'm dealing with a large amount of data in the input?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so my problem is,
>
> How do I avoid the 456 value from appearing twice?

**Here is a simple way to produce the wanted result without changing the expected order** of the sequence of resulting elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kF1" match="Field1" use="."/>
 <xsl:key name="kF2" match="Field2" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="row/Field1[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kF1',.)[1])]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "row/Field2[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kF2',.)[1])
      and
        not(key('kF1', .))]"/>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Field1 | Field2">
    <test><xsl:value-of select="."/></test>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided source XML document:**

```
<data>
    <row>
        <Field1>ABC</Field1>
        <Field2>123</Field2>
        <tag3>BLAH</tag3>
        <tag4>BLAH1</tag4>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Field1>ABC</Field1>
        <Field2>789</Field2>
        <tag3>BLAH</tag3>
        <tag4>BLAH1</tag4>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Field1>DEF</Field1>
        <Field2>456</Field2>
        <tag3>BLAH3</tag3>
        <tag4>BLAH4</tag4>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Field1>456</Field1>
        <Field2>XYZ</Field2>
        <tag3>BLAH5</tag3>
        <tag4>BLAH6</tag4>
    </row>
</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<test>ABC</test>
<test>DEF</test>
<test>456</test>
<test>123</test>
<test>789</test>
<test>XYZ</test>
```

> could you please point me to the most effecient way to achieve this as
>   I'm dealing with a large amount of data in the input?

If you perform sorting, as recommended by others, this is `O(N*Log(N))`, where N is the number of unique string values of the elements `Field1` and `Field2` in the source XML document.

The solution above doesn't do any sorting and the additional `not(key('kF1', .))]` is only `O(M)`, where M is the number of the unique string values of the `Field2` elements of the source XML document.

**Thus, this solution is more efficient** than using sorting to re-establish the original order -- significantly so in the case of "large amount of data in the input" .

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. The method works perfectly with what I need to achieve. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="Field1or2Key" match="Field1 | Field2" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="(row/Field1 | row/Field2)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Field1or2Key', .)[1])]">
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>      
            </test>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the order of the nodes is different. If this matters, use `xsl:sort` to get the order you need.

---

**Added:**

As Dimitre Novatchev notes, if you have a large input, sorting is probably not the optimal solution for you. I suspect that the order does **not** matter in fact, so I will not post an alternative solution (which would have to be more complicated).